# How can I call a function on start and periodically on Playframework 2.5

Tags: java, web-services, scheduled-tasks, playframework-2.5, onstart

I need to make a `WS` petition when I start play so I can log in a external service to obtain a token. I need that token for make future petitions. I know how to make WS petitions, I don't know where to place that code to execute on start. At this time, it is in a function of a controller.

If you want some code of this:

```
// login data
  ObjectNode tvdbaccount = Json.newObject();
  tvdbaccount.put("apikey", "*****");
  tvdbaccount.put("username", "*****");
  tvdbaccount.put("userkey", "*****");

  // try to login
  String token = "";
  CompletionStage<JsonNode> request = WS.url("https://api.thetvdb.com/login")
                                        .post(tvdbaccount)
                                        .thenApply(WSResponse::asJson);

  try {
    JsonNode response = request.toCompletableFuture()
                               .get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    token = response.get("token").asText();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
```

That token expires after 24 hours so I want for example to call a function every 12 hours that refreshes that token. That function is similar to the previous one, it's only a WS petition.

I'm using `playframework 2.5` where `GlobalSettings` is deprecated and I see multiple answers not very clear for 2.5 so I fail to get it done.

Comment: Added code to show what i'm doing

Comment: You might want to have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007478/was-asynchronous-jobs-removed-from-the-play-framework-what-is-a-better-alternat/31019858#31019858
Should be the same for play 2.5, Eager Singletons would be what you want to use for start up instead of deprecated GlobalSettings. See migration guide as well: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/GlobalSettings#Java

Comment: For repeating the task to fetch the token you can create an actor in the eager binding on startup that is called every 12 hours following the docs  at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAkka#Scheduling-asynchronous-tasks for periodically executed tasks.

Comment: Thank you, if I get something consistent, I will post it as a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alexander B, I've been able to get what I wanted.

## Eager Singleton

I resolved the `on start` function call with the [`eager singleton`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings).

What I've done is a class for the TVDB things and the important part is to write what you want to do on start **inside the constructor** of this class. And then to `bind` it on a module:

```
bind(TVDB.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

## Akka actors

For the `periodically` function call I used an [`Akka actor`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAkka).

I've implemented an actor which **calls itself** every 12 hours, so I placed the scheduling code in the same actor on the `preStart` void. I think the Playframework documentation for the `Scheduling asynchronous tasks` isn't updated and doesn't work the way it is (at least for me).

Then, I binded it on the module:

```
bindActor(TVDBActor.class, "TVDBActor");
```

If someone need the actor code here it is:

```
public class TVDBActor extends UntypedActor {

  @Inject
  public void preStart(final ActorSystem system, @Named("TVDBActor") ActorRef tvdbActor) {
    system.scheduler().schedule(
      Duration.create(12, TimeUnit.HOURS),
      Duration.create(12, TimeUnit.HOURS),
      tvdbActor,
      "tick",
      system.dispatcher(),
      null
    );
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
    TVDB.refreshToken();
  }

}
```